# How to format a number attribute with "new mongoose.Schema"?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, formatting

Could you tell what is the problem with

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: String,
  number: Number,
  date: Date,
  important: Boolean,
})
```

api.post code:

```
const person = new Person({
    content: body.content,
    important: body.important || false,
    date: new Date(),
  })
```

the test result I get miss "number" attribute in this format. being:

```
{
    "content": "hellas",
    "date": "2022-03-11T18:28:25.336Z",
    "important": false,
    "id": "622b94c96c5a07a4c0eb7222"
}
```

Could you share how to make a number attribute with Mongoose?

Comment: Could you paste the object that you are passing when you instance the mongoose model?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, when encounter this, you need to modify the api.post code section to:

```
const person = new Person({
    content: body.content,
    number: body.number,
    important: body.important || false,
    date: new Date(),
  })
```